# import theano using GPU Exception: The nvidia driver version installed with this OS does not give good results for reduction

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

I installed theano on WIN10, and it can be imported using CPU.
My graphics card is GTX1080. I installed CUDA8.0. Here is nvcc -V information:
[image]

And I also run the deviceQuery.cpp in cuda samples, result = PASS. Here is the result:
[image]

I also configured the .theanorc.txt：

[image]

But when I import theano, it comes 2 warnings and 
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 1080 (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 5005)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ", line 1, in 
File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano__init__.py, line 116, in theano.sandbox.cuda.tests.test_driver.test_nvidia_driver1()
File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda\tests\test_driver.py, line 41, in test_nvidia_driver1
raise Exception(The nvidia driver version installed with this OS

Exception: The nvidia driver version installed with this OS does not give good results for reduction.Installing the nvidia driver available on the same download page as the cuda package will fix the problem: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

[image]

CUDA8.0 driver version is 376.51, and I indeed installed this version.
I don't know where going wrong.
Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem during instalation of theano following [this guide](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5348). 
Beat this with installing top anaconda(5.0.0), creating environment with NOT top python (3.5 when top is 3.6) and installing NOT top cuda(8.0 when top is 9.0).

I'm not sure it helps you, but it can helps some people in future.